# Recursive way to calculate distance among co-ordinates

Tags: c#, recursion, c#-4.0

I am able to calculate the distance between two points(Latitude and Longtitude) by using the below function

```
public static double GetDistance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2)
{
            double sLatitude = 48.672309;
            double sLongitude = 15.695585;
            double eLatitude = 48.237867;
            double eLongitude = 16.389477;

            var coordinate1 = new GeoCoordinate(lat1, lng1);
            var coordinate2 = new GeoCoordinate(lat2, lng2);

            var resultInMeter = coordinate1.GetDistanceTo(coordinate2); //in meters

            //convert to KM : 1 meter = 0.001 KM
            var resultInKM = resultInMeter * 0.001; //in KM's

       return resultInKM ;
}
```

this works as under

```
double lat1 = 48.672309;
double lng1 = 15.695585;
double lat2 = 48.237867;
double lng2 = 16.389477;

var distance = GetDistance(lat1,lng1,lat2,lng2);
```

Now say I have a collection of Latitudes and Longtitudes as under

```
double[,] arrLatLong = new double[,]
             {
                {22.57891304, 88.34285622},
                {22.54398196, 88.38221001},
                {22.58277011, 88.38303798},
                {22.59950095, 88.39352995},
                {22.59887647, 88.32905243},
             };
```

How to calculate the total distance? Is there any recursive way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Trying to use recursion will only make this problem more difficult. Plain old iteration is more than sufficient.

```
double dist = 0.0;

for (int i = 0; i < arrLatLong.GetLength(0) - 1; i++)
{
    dist += GetDistance(
                arrLatLong[i, 0], 
                arrLatLong[i, 1], 
                arrLatLong[i+1, 0], 
                arrLatLong[i+1, 1]);
}
```

---

If you absolutely must use a recursive method, this should do the trick:

```
double GetDistanceRecursive(double[,] coords, int idx)
{
    if (idx + 1 >= coords.Length) 
        return 0.0;

    double dist = GetDistance(
                    coords[idx, 0], 
                    coords[idx, 1], 
                    coords[idx+1, 0], 
                    coords[idx+1, 1]);

    dist += GetDistanceRecursive(coords, idx + 1);

    return dist;
}
```

Comment: nice... just change from i < arrLatLong.Length - 1 to arrLatLong.GetUpperBound(0) for the iterative approach.

Comment: @priyanka.sarkar I'd prefer `GetLength(0)` myself, but yeah.